# where we put ejb program in tomcat 6.0 and how to deploy?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, tomcat6

I do not have eclipse. and I am having Tomcat 6.0.I write the programs in notepad. and I was successfully run the servlet programs. but I am not know about EJB. that is "where we put the .class files(In which directory)?". and "how to run and how to deploy the EJB programs?" please give sample example. please help me.

Comment: I would recomand that you take a look to the Java EE tutorial, so you will get a view on the services and abstraction Java EE application server can give you.  A quik transversal reading should give you an idea of what you need to solve your problemes.

Answer (score 3):

Tomcat 6.0 is not an EJB container. EJB's are a rather advanced topic. Do not haste into it. You can jump a mighty long way with servlets without ever needing EJB's or EJB containers.

If you need more services to  base your app on, look at Spring, which offers (almost) everything an EJB capable container offers and allows your programs to run on Tomcat 6.

Also Java is a bit verbose to use notepad for non trivial projects. You might consider to upgrade to an environment which gives better support. I am partial to IntelliJ myself, but netbeans and eclipse are nice too for that kind of development.

If you like to stick to notepad approach, you might take a look at grails. It offers all the services but uses groovy as the programming language which makes things a lot more compact allowing to develop JVM based web apps using a lean editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can run only web applications with Tomcat . For application s developed using EJB Use JBOSS. But JBOSS may be very slow. So while development use glassfish.   Tomcat is only for jsp and servlets. When it comes to EJB its enterprise application and have to use EJB container like JBOSS or some other EJB container.

Comment: JBoss AS 7 has similar performance (start up time, memory foot print, disk size) than Glassfish 3 and Tomcat.